# how to save a file in the same directory as the macro is saved

Tags: excel, vba, directory

this is my code

```
 Sub teste3()
 
 
 ' Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 
 Dim car As Variant Dim caminho As String
 
 ReDim car(1 To 4)
 
 
 
 Set b = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
 
 For i = 4 To 100000
 
     If b.Cells(i, 9) = Empty Then Exit For
 
     ' Number of columns in the staging area
     
             car(1) = b.Cells(i, 9)
             car(2) = b.Cells(i, 10)
             car(3) = b.Cells(i, 12)
             car(4) = b.Cells(i, 14)
    
         Range("B16").Select
         Application.CutCopyMode = False
         ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = car(3)
         Range("B17").Select
 
         Range("B17").Select
         Application.CutCopyMode = False
         ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = car(4)
         Range("B18").Select
 
 Dim oWs As Worksheet Dim oRng As Range Dim oChrtO As ChartObject Dim
 lWidth As Long, lHeight As Long
     
     Set oWs = ActiveSheet
     Set oRng = oWs.Range("A1:F13")
      oRng.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture
 
  lWidth = oRng.Width  lHeight = oRng.Height
 
 Set oChrtO = oWs.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=0, Top:=0, Width:=lWidth,
 Height:=lHeight)
 
  oChrtO.Activate  With oChrtO.Chart
         .Paste
         '.sa Filename:=EstaPastaDeTrabalho.Path & car(1) & "_" & Replace(car(2), "/", "_") & "_Barr_" & car(3) * 100 & "_cup_" & car(4)
 * 100 & ".jpg"
         .Export Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & car(1) & "_" & Replace(car(2), "/", "_") & "_Barr_" & car(3) * 100 & "_cup_" & car(4)
 * 100 & ".jpg"
             
         'Set down 1 row from present location End With
 
 oChrtO.Delete
 
 
       Next i
          'With Application ' '    .ScreenUpdating = True '    .DisplayAlerts = True '    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
 
 End Sub
```

but the file is not saving in my directory, hi is saving a pasth before this, how can I do this code better?

I need him to save these files in the folder where the macro is saved, but I can't put the name of the folder because I want to change it from the folder and make it keep saving only in the name folder, without me changing the name

Comment: The path where the "macro", that is the workbook is saved is ActiveWorkbook.Path. 
View it: Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.Path

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.Path` doesn't include a final \ so you need to add that before you concatenate the rest of the path for saving